# Determine if a function is even or odd

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Define $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$h(x)=f(x)\{f(x)+f(-x)\}$$

Then, which of the following option(s) is/are correct ?

(A) h is even for all f

(B) h is odd for all f

(C) h is even if f is even

(D) h is even if f is odd.

My Steps:

If f(x) is even, $h(x)=2\{f(x)\}^3$. f(x) being even, h(x) is also even.

If f(x) is odd, $h(x)=0$, but that would make h both odd and even.

So, the correct answer would be ONLY option (C) ?

Did I solve this correctly ?

Comment: You seem to have made a slight mistake. When $f(x)$ is even, $h(x)=2\{f(x)\}^2$. Although that doesn't change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is even, then $h$ is odd (as you have said), so $d)$ is also true.

Comment: so that would make options A,C and D correct ?

Comment: A is incorrect. $h$ is even only if $f$ is odd or even, not for all functions $f$.